# Join multiple dataframes while retaining the row count of the main dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have a pandas dataframe that I am using to create 2 additional dataframes. After the creation of the two dataframes, I want to merge the two with the original dataframe retaining the count of the original. Is there an easier way of doing it?

Original dataframe example:

[image: Original dataframe example]

First dataframe example:

[image: First Dataframe example]

Second dataframe example:

[image: Second dataframe example]

Final output should look like this :

[image: Final output]

When I try to do it, I am either getting double the number of rows or half the number of rows.

Comment: Please post attempted code. If none, please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) horizontal merge with `pandas.concat`. Then, give it a try and return with *specific* question.

Comment: Do the `Column1` is relevant because it's not possible to guess the `cccc` has the letter `r`?

Answer (score 0):

After reformatted the third dataframe, you can merge each of them:

```
df3a = df3.rename(columns={'Column4': 'Column2'}).drop_duplicates('Column2')
```

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, on='Column2', how='outer') \
       .merge(df3a, on='Column2', how='outer')

  Column1 Column2  Column3  Column5 Column6
0       p    eeee      3.0        7       7
1       q    dddd      6.0        6       6
2       s    bbbb      4.0        4       4
3       t    aaaa      1.0        3       3
4       u    ssss      4.0        2       3
5       v    rrrr      2.0        1       1
6     NaN    cccc      NaN        5       5
```